# Mysql, select statement referencing on date(weekofyear)

Tags: mysql, date, left-join, gaps-and-islands

I've been working on this issue the past week or so and I can't seem to come up with a solution.
I am trying to create a query, where I am fetching for data from various tables, primarily I'm aggregating the date on weeks(weekofyear). Therefore I created a calendar table as depicted below;

```
   DATE,    YEAR, MONTH_OF_YEAR, WEEK_OF_YEAR,

2014-01-01  2014       1               1
2014-01-02  2014       1               1
2014-01-03  2014       1               1
2014-01-04  2014       1               1
2014-01-05  2014       1               1
2014-01-06  2014       1               2
```

The data goes on until whenever.

So, I've all these tables and data that I aggregate and want results say for the past 10 weeks and for the weeks that there has been no activity i want a 0.

I wrote this query to fetch data from 2 tables and join them on week_of_year of the calendar table (please don't crucify me, SQL isn't my first language).

```
select calendar.YEAR,
       calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,
       ifnull(count(data_transfer.id_data_transfer), 0) as DEVICE_TO_DEVICE,
       ifnull(count(device.tag_code), 0) as DEVICE_REGISTRATION
from calendar
left join data_transfer 
    on data_transfer.WEEK_NUMBER=calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR -- wee number
        and data_transfer.year = calendar.YEAR -- need the year of week
        and data_transfer.id_customer = 1 --  specific customer
        and data_transfer.cloud_type is null --  specific type etc
        and date(data_transfer.TRANSFER_START_TIME) > date(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) -- for the final week to be this week
left join device 
    on device.WEEK_NUMBER = calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR       
        and device.year = calendar.YEAR
        and device.ID_CUSTOMER = 1
        and date(device.DEVICE_CREATE_DATE) > date(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) -- for the final week to be this week
where date(calendar.date) > date(date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) -- for the final week to be this week
group by calendar.year, calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR
order by calendar.year, calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
```

The query returns multiple doubles, I think this may be due to the date table having multiple entries for week_of_year i.e 7 due to the days in the week?

for example when I run it with group_concat(specific_field) i get the results down as shown. That's the issue I am trying to account for

```
YEAR, WEEK_OF_YEAR, DEVICE_TO_DEVICE, DEVICE_REGISTRATION, group_concat(data_transfer.id_data_transfer), id
2014    46  280 280 50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57
```

That's the issue above is the issue I am trying to account for, any help in regards to it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is that you have multiple records with the same year and week of year values.

1. Either create a calendar table where there is only one year - week of year pair in the table and use that to join your log data on.
2. Or use select distinct in your query.

```sql
    select distinct calendar.YEAR,
       calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,
       ifnull(count(data_transfer.id_data_transfer), 0) as DEVICE_TO_DEVICE,
       ifnull(count(device.tag_code), 0) as DEVICE_REGISTRATIO
     from...
```

3. Or Get the distinct year - week of year pairs from your calendar table in a subquery and join this derived table on device and data_transfer tables.

```sql
select c.YEAR,
       c.WEEK_OF_YEAR,
       ifnull(count(data_transfer.id_data_transfer), 0) as DEVICE_TO_DEVICE,
       ifnull(count(device.tag_code), 0) as DEVICE_REGISTRATION
from (select distinct YEAR, WEEK_OF_YEAR FROM calendar) c
left join data_transfer 
    on data_transfer.WEEK_NUMBER=c.WEEK_OF_YEAR -- wee number
        and data_transfer.year = c.YEAR -- need the year of week
        and data_transfer.id_customer = 1 --  specific customer
        and data_transfer.cloud_type is null --  specific type etc
        and date(data_transfer.TRANSFER_START_TIME) > date(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) -- for the final week to be this week
left join device 
    on device.WEEK_NUMBER = c.WEEK_OF_YEAR       
        and device.year = c.YEAR
        and device.ID_CUSTOMER = 1
        and date(device.DEVICE_CREATE_DATE) > date(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) -- for the final week to be this week
where date(calendar.date) > date(date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) -- for the final week to be this week
group by c.year, c.WEEK_OF_YEAR
order by c.year, c.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
```

Comment: I'll look into the distinct function for mysql see where I can go from there. You wouldn't have some time to give me an example of what you have in mind would you? Thanks btw you have answered a few of my questions in other topics.

Comment: I have not figured out yet how to combine neatly formatted code with a numbered list, but I'll give a try again. The simples use of distinct is to insert distinct keyword after your select keyword.

Comment: Okay @shadow, that looks like a good start for me, I'll chance my arm and see where I can go with it. Thank you again for your time good sir.